# Singleton Kotlin class extending RoomDatabase is called just once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using a Java codebase of an app to build another app in Kotlin. I've written a class `AppDatabase` extending `RoomDatabase` that is a singleton. It works once, and the other times the class isn't called. This is the class:

```
@Database(entities = [Classes::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun classesDao() : ClassesDao
}

object DatabaseProvider {
    private var database: String = "db_classes"
    private var sInstance: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context) : AppDatabase {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                database
            ).build()
        }

        return sInstance!!
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` displays a `CalendarView` that will fetch data by the selected date (so far it fetches after I pressed a date).

```
...
    ...
    mCalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendar)
    mCalendar?.setOnDateChangeListener { _, y, m, d ->
        mSelectedDate = DateUtils.convertToDate(y.toString(), m.toString(), d.toString())
        fetchClasses()
    }
    ...
...

private fun fetchClasses() {
    val modelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(this.applicationContext, mSelectedDate!!)
    val classesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, modelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    classesViewModel.getClasses().observe(this, Observer<List<Classes>> {
        if (it!!.isEmpty()) {
            mRvClasses?.visibility = View.GONE
            mTvNoClasses?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mImgNoClasses?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        mAdapter?.setClasses(it)
    })
}
```

The `MainViewModel`:

```
class MainViewModel(context: Context, date: String) : ViewModel() {
    private var classes: LiveData<List<Classes>>?  = null
    private var db: AppDatabase? = null

    init {
        db = DatabaseProvider.getInstance(context)
        classes = db?.classesDao()?.getClassesByDate(date)
    }

    fun getClasses() : LiveData<List<Classes>> {
        return classes!!
    }
}
```

It works, but I noticed that if I switch the date, it will not be called anymore. If I, for example after the app opens select one date only, I can store as many records for that date as I want, but the moment I switch the date, it will stop being called and inserted.

This is the Java code I based on:

```
@Database(entities = { TaskEntry.class }, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todolist";
    private static AppDatabase sInstance;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).build();
            }
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    public abstract TaskDao taskDao();
}
```

Comment: What won't be called anymore, `getClasses()` ?

Comment: Yes. If I change the date after picking one nothing will work anymore, querying and inserting.

Comment: I guess you need Transformations https://medium.com/google-developers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7. Check the link if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan, it looks like it could help. I am trying to implement it but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke a new `SQL` query when the date is modified. First, modify your `ViewModel` so that it reacts to `Date` changes:

```
class MainViewModel(context: Context, date: String) : ViewModel() {
    private var db: AppDatabase? = null
    private val dateInput = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val classes: LiveData<List<Classes>>

    init {
        db = DatabaseProvider.getInstance(context)
        dateInput.value = date
        classes = Transformations.switchMap(dateInput, {
            db?.classesDao()?.getClassesByDate(it)
        })
    }

    fun setDate(date: String) {
        dateInput.value = date
    }
}
```

Then, in your `MainActivity` `onCreate(...)` each time a `Date` changes just call `classesViewModel.setDate(mSelectedDate)`. I removed `fetchClasses()` because there's no need to call each time but only in `onCreate`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    mCalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendar)
    mCalendar?.setOnDateChangeListener { _, y, m, d ->
        mSelectedDate = DateUtils.convertToDate(y.toString(), m.toString(), d.toString())
        // just update the date and nothing else is needed 
        classesViewModel.setDate(mSelectedDate)
    }
    val modelFactory = MainViewModelFactory(this.applicationContext, mSelectedDate)
    val classesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, modelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)    
    classesViewModel.classes.observe(this, Observer<List<Classes>> {
        if (it!!.isEmpty()) {
            mRvClasses?.visibility = View.GONE
            mTvNoClasses?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mImgNoClasses?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        mAdapter?.setClasses(it)
    })
    ...
}
```

For more info please look [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: Hi, thank you, but there are some errors showing up. The `classes` declaration is written in Java while the rest of the code is Kotlin, the `dateInput` doesn't exist, the second parameter of `switchMap` requires a `LiveData`... I tried adjusting it and guessing the other issues.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 Sorry, fixed.

Comment: My friend, it worked. I am experiencing some problems with the condition checking if the returned data is null, but nothing related to the question. So, you have my thanks. This is new to me, seems impossible at the first sight, but with time I can understand it better. Thank you.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 You're very welcome! I'm happy it helped you!